# ffmpeg timecode based on filename

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, exiftool

I have xxxxx videofiles that need to get a timecode (for working in premiere)
The  filenames are all like this 2023-03-08 12.59.59 AndSomeRandowNumbers.
Is that possible with ffmpeg?
Or if that is not possible: can ffmpeg use an other date from the metadata and use that as timecode (with exiftool is possible to use the filename and write it as  creation date, and other, but not as timecode)?

ffmpeg -i file.mov -map 0 -map -0:d -c copy -timecode 02:10:22:33 outputfile.mov
that is the code that works to change the timecode to 02:10:22:33